# Как убрать отступ после изображения

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет.
Проблема с отображением текста и изображения на WordPress.

В редакторе все отлично:

А на сайте отображается уже иначе

Comment: Смотрите стили элементов через инспектор. Нужно убрать марджины.

Comment: Я добавил в <img style="margin-right: 0px;"  -  и это помогло

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вам прийдеться либо переопределить CSS стили для какого-то из классов `alignnone size-full wp-image-163` этих изображений, или же добавить этим классам собственный CSS class и уже ему назаначить стили которые будут сбрашивать дефолтные настройки.